# Hash md5 email in Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, md5, google-tag-manager, looker-studio

I have in my Tag Manager a variable {{Email - not encrypted}} that contains a string (email address or empty) but not hashed in md5. 
I need to encrypt/hash this data in md5 in order to send it to some tags. 
I know to do it quickly and I don't have access to the code. 
Here is the script I tried to put as custom HTML in Tag Manager but it doesn't work. (error Parse error. primary expression expected. 
I'm Really new with JavaScript so I don't know/understand what is wrong. 
Here is my script :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-md5/2.10.0/js/md5.min.js"></script>
<script>
function() {
    var hash = CryptoJS.MD5({{Email - not encrypted}});
    return hash;
    }
</script>
```

Thanks for your help.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you need to use a GTM custom Javascript variable based on your 'raw' variable, with your function placed in the custom Javascript window like so:

```
function() {
  var hash = CryptoJS.MD5({{Email - not encrypted}});
  return hash;    
}
```

(Not custom HTML, custom Javascript.)

Comment: Hi! Is there a way to import the CryptoJS library via GTM so that it is available for the variable? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.